# How to achieve next and previous row in a query

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this in MYSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table 

id  u_id  name   date
1   101   name2  2012-05-14
2   305   name3  2012-05-11
3   506   name4  2012-05-05
4   207   name5  2012-05-12
5   108   name6  2012-05-03

SELECT id,u_id from test_table order by date;

id  u_id

5    108
3    506
2    305
4    207
1    101
```

I have a application where where these things are displayed

on clicking on  any `u_id` it takes me to a different page which displyed details stuff
Now I want to write a query which willl give me the next record

How do I achive the next record from here like

when I say `u_id>305` it shoud give me `207`?
and `u_id<305` it should give me `506`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the u_id is 305, to get the next record by date:

```
SELECT id,u_id 
FROM test_table a
WHERE a.date > (SELECT date FROM test_table b WHERE b.u_id = 305)
ORDER BY a.date
LIMIT 1;
```

And to get the previous record by date:

```
SELECT id,u_id 
FROM test_table a
WHERE a.date < (SELECT date FROM test_table b WHERE b.u_id = 305)
ORDER BY a.date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT id, u_id 
FROM test_table 
WHERE uid > 305
ORDER BY date ASC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT id, u_id 
FROM test_table 
WHERE uid < 305
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: How come you need to use the original result set? I thought this was a completely different page. Can you not run some new queries for this new page?

Comment: For this solution, if you want performance, add a compound index on (uid, date).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select id,u_id from
  (SELECT id,u_id,@rownum:= @rownum+1 AS Sno 
  from test_table , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;
  order by date)a
  where Sno=<@ID-1/+1>
```

lets say if your current Sno=5 then 4 will give the previous record and 6 will give the next record